# How can I integrate an SMS gateway with an existing web app?

Tags: asp.net, json, sms-gateway

I am not sure if I am asking this in right forum or not. If not please guide to right one.

We need to integrate SMS gateway with an existing asp web app. Sounds easy, however difficult part is we dont have the code for the app and its deployed on the cloud.
Its a complain booking app, where in guest complains and user redirects it to concerning person. So we need to send sms to those concerning persons.
I checked the page source and I can see basic infos like Complain no., complaint persons name, date however there is a dropdownlist where users list is there, to whom to be forwarded, not able to get those on the aspx file.
I am guessing JSON or building chrome exxtension might do the work. However not too sure though. So please any one redirect me to right path will be a great help. 
If need any other info please let me know.
Thanks

EDIT:
I was thinking if I open URL in c# WINFORM , then I can I get data and perform task on click event of the website ?

Comment: Which server side language you used to build this app ?

Comment: We dont have the code for the app, we need to extract data when user press submit. That app is in asp